# C# отловить клик пользователя

Tags: c#, mouse-event

У меня такая проблема : мне нужно каким-либо образом отловить клик пользователя и вывести названия объекта в консоле, по какому он кликнул. Например, пользователь на рабочем столе кликнул на папку Folder. Следовательно, названия папки Folder должно быть выведено в консоль.

Comment: Клавиатурный шпион, посмотрите в поиске, на гитхабе. Смысл навесить хук на события мыши, примеров много.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться VisualTreeHelper (в wpf). При клике, сможешь поймать дерево, а уже из него вытащить, например, самый верхний элемент и информацию из него.
В особенности можно воспользоваться этим методом: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.hittest?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @alladuh Вот уж благодарен. Уже не надеялся получить ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно при отлове клика делать скриншот в области клика и делать распознавание текста по ней, но это конечно костыльно... Так на хабре делали чит, распознавали подпись над врагом и таким образом понимали, куда надо стрелять